# Добавить библиотеку элементов управления в проект

Tags: c#, .net-core, library

Я в Visual Studio Community 2019 (Версия 16.9.2) создаю Библиотеку элементов управления Windows Forms на базе .NET Core 3.1. Далее делаю в проекте свои элементы управления.

После я создаю проект Windows Forms на платформе .NET Core 3.1 и добавляю ранее созданную библиотеку этот проект. Но на панель элементов новые элементы не добавляются.

Подскажите, как мне добавить элементы управления в проект из сторонней библиотеки?

Comment: Похоже, это пока не реализовано. Тут два выхода: либо добавлять эти контролы на форму вручную, в коде, без дизайнера. Либо скопировать cs-код контролов прямо в основной проект, благо он у вас есть.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я так и понял, так как Microsoft предлагает создать VSIX, но это полное засорение панели. Также, VS постоянно сносит пользовательские элементы с формы, которые я добавил раннее. Как бороться с этой бедой пока не представляю.

Comment: Использование .NET 5, вместо .NET Core 3.1 не спасает ситуацию?

Comment: Я не пробовал, но решил, пока переносить их не библиотекой, а классами. Думаю в Microsoft знают о данной проблеме, и сейчас устраняют ее))

Comment: Как я понял, Для того, чтобы элементы добавились, достаточно просто подтянуть библиотеку, но элементы по какой-то причине не подтягиваются. Также заметил, что если использовать framework data.mysql, то от него подтягиваются элементы. То есть во framework от mikrosoft такой проблемы не наблюдается.)))

Comment: `Думаю в Microsoft знают о данной проблеме, и сейчас устраняют ее))` как вы узнали, что они еще не устранили, если `Я не пробовал`?

Comment: Я говорю про net core 3.1. А не пробовал .NET 5

Comment: Visual Studio до последней версии обновите, в 16.8.* у меня вообще данная функция не работала.

Comment: У меня последняя версия.